# Parse config file in C/C++

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie looking for a fast and easy way to parse a text file in C or C++ (wxWidgets)

The file will look something like this (A main category with "sub-objects") which will appear in a list box

```
[CategoryA]

[SubCat]

    Str1 = Test 

    Str2 = Description  

[SubCat] [End]

[SubCat]

    Str1 = Othertest
...

[CategoryA] [End]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you write your own format you probably have to write your own parser. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler

Comment: If you use GTK. You can use the Glib KeyFile `save_to_file` and `load_from_file`. https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.KeyFile.html

Answer (score 16):

Sounds like you want to parse a file that's pretty close to an ini file.

There's at least a few INI parser libraries out there: [minIni](http://www.compuphase.com/minini.htm), [iniParser](http://ndevilla.free.fr/iniparser/), [libini](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libini/), for instance.

Answer (score 15):

It should be fairly easy to write your own parser for this if you use streams. You can read a file using an `std::ifstream`:

```
std::ifstream ifs("filename.ext");
if(!ifs.good()) throw my_exceptions("cannot open file");
read_file(ifs);
```

Since it seems line-oriented, you would then first read lines, and then process these:

```
void read_file(std::istream& is) 
{
  for(;;) {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(is, line);
    if(!is) break;
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    // read from iss 
  }
  if(!is.eof()) throw my_exceptions("error reading file");
}
```

For the actual parsing, you could `1)` first peek at the first character. If that's a `[`, pop it from the stream, and use `std::getline(is,identifier,']')` to read whatever is within '[' and ']'. If it isn't a `[`, use `std::getline(is, key, '=')` to read the left side of a key-value pair, and then `std::getline(is, value)` to read the right side.

Note: Stream input, unfortunately, is usually not exactly lightning fast. (This doesn't have to be that way, but in practice this often is.) However, it is really easy to do and it is fairly easy to do it right, once you know a very few patterns to work with its peculiarities (like `if(strm.good())` not being the same as `if(strm)` and not being the opposite of `if(strm.bad())` and a few other things you'll have to get used to). For something as performance-critical (har har!) as reading an ini file from disk, it should be fast enough in 999,999 out of 1,000,000 cases.

Comment: Three years later, but a very informative answer. I'm quite new to file streams and you supplied all the information I'd need to make a basic parser without any additional libraries (Mostly I like the whole getline argument to get a string between specific characters). I wish I could give more than one +1.

Answer (score 9):

You may want to try [Boost.Program_Options](http://www.boost.org/libs/program_options/). However it has slightly different formatting. More close to INI files. Subcategories are done like this:

```
[CategoryA]
Option = Data

[CategoryB.Subcategory1]
Option = Data

[CategoryB.Subcategory2]
Option = Data
```

Also it has some other features so it is actually very useful IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Try Configurator. It's easy-to-use and flexible C++ library for configuration file parsing (from simplest INI to complex files with arbitrary nesting and semantic checking). Header-only and cross-platform. Uses Boost C++ libraries.

See: http://opensource.dshevchenko.biz/configurator

Answer (score 1):

It looks more straightforward to implement your own parser than to try to adapt an existing one you are unfamiliar with.

Your structure seems - from your example - to be line-based.  This makes parsing it easy.

It generally makes sense to load your file into a tree, and then walk around it as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows only, [`GetPrivateProfileSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724348(v=vs.85).aspx) does this. It's deprecated in favor of the registry but it's still here and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to make a simple XML file? There are plenty of libraries that can help you read it, and the added bonus is that a lot of other programs/languages can read it too.

Comment: I have found the overhead of not necessarily the parsing but the binding of xml files to the data not worth the effort for simple configuration files. If you have something that creates the bindings it is a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using wxWidgets I would consider [wxFileConfig](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxfileconfig.html#wxfileconfig). I'm not using wxWidgets, but the class seems to support categories with sub-categories.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using GTK, you are lucky.

You can use the Glib KeyFile `save_to_file` and `load_from_file`.
https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.KeyFile.html

Or when using Gtkmm (C++).
See: https://developer-old.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1KeyFile.html

Example in C++ with `load_from_file`:

```
#include <glibmm.h>
#include <string>

Glib::KeyFile keyfile;
keyfile.load_from_file(file_path);
std::string path = keyfile.get_string("General", "Path");
bool is_enabled = keyfile.get_boolean("General", "IsEnabled");
```

Saving is as easy as calling `save_to_file`:

```
Glib::KeyFile keyfile;
keyfile.set_string("General", "Path", path);
keyfile.set_boolean("General", "IsEnabled", is_enabled);
keyfile.save_to_file(file_path);
```