# How I can read strings after specific character (like '=') from files?

Tags: c++

I have a file 'config.ini' and I would store some settings info in it.

For example:

```
##CONFIG.INI##
#window-resolution = 1920x1080
#player-movement = 100
#appstate = state_menu
```

Now how I can read data after the '=' from my file to my variables? I think I have to use `std::getline`, but I don't know how.

Comment: This should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Yes getline to read line per line, when scanf to extract word after '=' if present. Don't be afraid to do and show, is simple to do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I can read data after '=' from my file to my variables?

Learn more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques, notably about [recursive descent parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Indeed, you should read the entire line (e.g. with `std::getline`, or perhaps even [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) on Linux, if the configuration is interactive) then use appropriate parsing techniques on the line you have got.

Consider reading the first half of the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). It should help you a lot.

You could also find some free software libraries (like [libconfig](https://github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig) and many others) to parse configuration files. See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6892754/841108) related question.

You could also use parser generators like [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) (to be perhaps used with [flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator))) or [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/). They would generate for you some C or C++ code, once you provided them some annotated grammar describing your input language. For documentation purposes at least, you want to describe that input language (something explaining the expected contents of your `config.ini`) in [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation.