# Is there anyway to use environment variables to initialize static variables in C++?

Tags: c++, environment-variables

I’m stuck with this dilemma where I need to use **environment variables to initialize static variables** in my application but from the C++ standard

> Variables with static storage duration are initialized as a consequence of program initiation… —-ISO/IEC 14882:2020(E) section 6.9.3.2

But for me, it is also during this program initiation that my environment variables are set. So it ends up being that the variables get requested for when they have not yet been set.

Can you suggest a work around to solve this?

Comment: You may want to defer loading these until you're *sure* the application is fully initialized.

Comment: Please throw more light

Comment: If you try and evaluate these as a `constexpr` and yet they're *not* constant as they depend on `ENV` variables that can change, you'll end up in a world of hurt. I'd suggest making a singleton accessor that will initialize these on first call, then saves the value for subsequent calls to avoid having to re-evaluate it.

Comment: Using environment variables for program-controlled initialization seems a bit baroque. Why not just set the desired values? That doesn't avoid the initialization order issues, but it makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: @PeteBecker you do have a point. I just want to avoid recompiling code when a variable will be changed. Especially a variable like an int used to know log rotation e.t.c

Comment: For me this is [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Why you need this? Are we taking about runtime feature (then why this must be static variable) or compile time feature (where constant are set at compile time)?

Comment: I personally would prefer command line arguments over environment variables anyway...

Comment: @MarekR cheers for bringing this up. It might be the case so let me bring the original problem. I made a comment to Marcus Muller’s answer. Please contribute to the conversation, it will be really helpful.

Comment: @Aconcagua I thought hard on this and went with env because there are just a ton of variables like these

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon this proves my point. Even answers show some level of confusion what is your goal and alerts "don't do that". I would recommend you to [edit] your question and clarify what ind of functionality you need fro end user point of view. You can start  from sentence like "As a end user I'd like that application is .... based on system environment variables .... so application can do .... " (this is agile pattern to describe "User stories").

Comment: Your basic assumption to use global variables is already questionable and will make your code hard to unit test. In your tests you should also be able to simulate what happens if environment variables have bad values. So just read them at startup into a "config" struct and inject that struct into code that needs those variables. This allows you unit test to programmatically create config struct instances with a wide variety of valid and invalid values.

Comment: A good idea. I haven’t really used configuration structs before and I’m weary of compilation especially during a simple change.

Comment: If you have so many configuration entries then yet another alternative to environment variables might be a configuration file – maybe selectable via command line parameter and still a default available if no parameter provided. This way you could easily switch between several configurations without having to mess with the system environment (and yes, you could set them via shell script or batch file as well, I know).

Comment: Why nobody asks for a minimal sample code? What's the necessity of static variables? Why should environment variables be used? The design is apparently broken. But I wonder how y'all guys want to fix this invisible code.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you mean when you say that the environment variables are set during program initiation?   Do you mean that (1) your program updates the environment variables, or (2) that some other process might update the variables while your program is initialising and your program needs to get the latest values?   The approaches needed are different in those two cases.

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks a lot. I looked into your suggestion and it seems that’s a very good work around this situation over using environment variables. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6892829/16770846  is the eye opener for me. Except that I don’t know if I can make the config file load upon program initiation.

Comment: @Peter yes no 1. My program sets it.

Comment: If your program is setting by your environment variables, then you need to orchestrate the order of things to maintain consistency.  For example, access the environmental variables to initialise your program and then - for example, immediately after initialisation - set all the environment variables consistently with the state of your program at that time (in the sense that, if you were to immediately reinitialise using the environment variables, your program would have identical state).

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon *'Except that I don’t know if I can make the config file load upon program initiation'* – if you mean *'needs to be done before main is called'* then you could write a class doing all this work in its default constructor and have a global instance of – **but** you risk ending up in static intialisation hell, if you have multiple global objects in different compilation units you cannot guarantee that the configuration is loaded already when other objects are created and try to access it!

Comment: I personally would rather do all such initialisations from within main as very first thing. You simply have better control over all of your initialisation process.

Comment: @tadman I will use block scope static variables then. I presume that this will mean only initialization only upon need on first function call. If this is what you meant then cheers . I will try to see how this plays out and if it is the best work around then I’ll post after. Once more, thanks y’all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a work around.

This is what I considered before I took the path to where I currently am.

> if you don't reliably set your environment prior to initialization, you cannot rely on it during initialization.
>
> [Marcus Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4433386/marcus-m%C3%BCller)

So I had to load my environment variables upon program initiation and before `main` execution.

```cpp
static int vars = load_env_vars();
int main(){ return 0; };
```

Still considering the *static initialization fiasco*, I had to defer the initialization of static variables that depend on these environment variables. [First suggestion on the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77375115/is-there-anyway-to-use-environment-variables-to-initialize-static-variables-in-c#comment136407271_77375115). Credit: [Tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman).

I did this by declaring the static variables on the call stack i.e. within functions so that they will be initialized once and only once upon function call and its value persists between calls. The code that needs the variable makes the function call. The good thing is that the variables will not be re-evaluated upon a second call and [returning a reference to it is safe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable#Static_local_variables) because it will live till the end of the program and will be destroyed i.e. destructors will be called, upon program exit.

See the ISO C++20 standard concerning static local scope variables.

> The keyword static can be used to declare a local variable with static storage duration. —-ISO/IEC 14882:2020(E) section 6.7.5.1

And destruction of static local scope variables.

> Constructed objects with static storage duration are destroyed and functions registered with std::atexit are called as part of a call to std::exit. The call to std::exit is sequenced before the destructions and the registered functions. [Note: Returning from main invokes std::exit (6.9.3.1). —end note] —-ISO/IEC 14882:2020(E) section 6.9.3.4

So the following worked.

```cpp
static_var& get_static_var()
{
    static static_var T{std::getenv(“KEY”)};
    return T;
};
```

Now a call to `get_static_var()` will initialize `T` giving it static storage duration and returning a reference to `T` -lazy initialization. Subsequent calls to `get_static_var()` [will still return the same instance of `T` by reference.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable#Static_local_variables)

Answer (score 2):

For namespace-level statics (probably what you're referring to), you can set your environment globals in `main`, and then have your special globals in other cpp files initialize themselves from those first globals, and hope your compiler lazily initializes the globals in other cpp files, but.... that's pretty much the root cause of the [static initialization order fiasco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822181/prevent-static-initialization-order-fiasco-c). It's a disaster, don't do that.

Instead, simply use method-level statics. This sidesteps the fiasco by guaranteeing that globals are initialized in the proper order, and is easy.

```
//environment globals
const environment_t& env() {
   static const environment_t values = {
           std::getenv("PATH"),
           std::getenv("HOME"),
           std::getenv("SHELL"),
           std::getenv("LOGNAME"),
           std::getenv("UID"),
           std::getenv("HOSTNAME"),
           std::getenv("MAIL"),
           std::getenv("EDITOR"),
           std::getenv("TEMP"),
       };
   return values;
}

// derived globals
const std::string& app_data_directory() {
    static const std::string value(env().home + "app/data"s);
    return value;
}

// safe and easy!
int main() {
    std::cout << app_data_directory();
}
```

https://ideone.com/TrbpW0

Comment: When someone writes `environment variables` my first though is [std::getenv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv).

Comment: @MarekR I was unaware of that method! I can definitely improve the answer with that, thanks!

Comment: @MooingDuck thanks for this. I have seen a whole different method I have never seen before right here in your code. I’m just trying to figure out how I might be able to use this to initialize static class members. Can you help? Let’s say there is a static class member as such: static environment_t home = std::getenv("HOME"); something like this. Can you give a guide?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon I don't understand your question. In this example, `app_data_directory` is my static object. You can't really do this for static class members really. They'll have to be non-members.

Answer (score 0):

As you say: if you don't reliably set your environment prior to initialization, you cannot rely on it during initialization.

So, no.

Comment: Too bad. The idea is essentially to have variables in static duration such that they will live throughout the lifetime of the program (especially within classes). But these variables are going to be set from the environment variables set straight from an env file.

Comment: that sounds like a strange design. You're trying to build global variables, so a lot of singletons. That's probably a bad idea. If you need to have a configuration singleton, let it be *one* object that you get from a function that returns a reference to an internal `static` element (which gets initialized by reading the config file when the function is run the first time).

Comment: Is it? I didn’t think it so. I have an example of where this is really useful to me. I have a Memento class. This class stores to disk. The idea is that it stores the objects in different files under one folder to be thread safe. It can be used in any thread. Any Memento instantiated will know the folder it should store to. This folder will be passed in through environment variables gotten from an env file. That being said, the user can change to any folder at their choosing. The Memento stores commands that mutate the system so that system recovery is possible.

Comment: environment variables are a terrible choice here. Don't do that.

Comment: Re: "environment variables gotten from an env file" -- if the code is reading data from a file, where do environment variables get into the mix? Environment variables are typically set **before** running the program.

Comment: The code sets it’s own environment variables actually. It sets it straight from an env file. This is where the problem comes from -I believe.

Comment: again, that's a very bad design. this is just global variables, put into the environment.