# Best way to parse a file in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, string, parsing, file

I am trying to parse out an apache-like config file using Objective-c.  Where is the best place to start?  I haven't done a lot of file read/write on this platform.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use NSString and NSScanner, but I generally find it easier just to use C APIs directly for pure ASCII files.

Things like:

http://www.mrx.net/c/readfunctions.html

http://bytes.com/topic/c/insights/657086-how-parse-file-c

And, on stack overflow:

[Parse config file in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417765/parse-config-file-in-c-c)

Answer (score 0):

The following classes are your friends:

- [NSString](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSString)
- [NSScanner](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSScanner)
- [NSFileManager](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSFileManager)