# why am I getting a error: no instance of an overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list here?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, getline, file-io

I have looked at a couple of links such as [this](http://www.bing.com/search?FORM=BDT3DF&PC=BDT3&dt=091613&q=how+to+use+getline+c%2B%2B&src=IE-SearchBox) and [this](http://www.bing.com/search?q=error%3A+no+instance+of+an+overloaded+function+%22getline%22+matches+the+argument+list&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=error%3A+no+instance+of+an+overloaded+function+%22getline%22+matches+the+argument+list&sc=0-5&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=f369ecc8b7ef4ff5a342595dd7c82f65).

Unfortunately I'm just to new of a programmer to figure it out. I would like to have the following as the line `while( getline(getline(fin, line) )` because I'm trying to read in the entire line of text from a file. Then I'm trying to figure out if there are any similar words or numbers in that file. I'm writing this in Microsoft visual studio 2012.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// main application entry point
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    string filename;
    ifstream inFile;

    // request the file name from the user
    cout << "Please enter a filename: ";

    // stores the users response in the string called filename
    cin >> (std::cin, filename);

    // opens the file
    inFile.open(filename.c_str());

    // if the file doesn't open
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file: " << filename << endl;

        return -1;

    } // end of if( !inFile )

    // while( getline(getline(fin, line) ) gives me the same error
    while (getline())
    {}

    // close the file
    inFile.close();

} // end of int main( int argc, char* argv[])
```

Comment: Just curious: What do you think `cin >> (std::cin, filename)` does?

Comment: I thought it did:

// stores the users response in the string called filename

but after your comment it would appear that I'm completely wrong.

Comment: No, you're right that it does that, it's just that you're doing it in an unnecessary way. `(std::cin, filename)` is the same as `filename` because the comma operator `,` returns the rightmost operand. All you really need is `std::cin >> filename`.

Comment: What's the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

> why am I getting a error: `no instance of an overloaded function “getline” matches the argument list` here?

Because you called `std::getline()` without any arguments, while `std::getline()` does require arguments:

```
while( getline() )
{
}
```

What `std::getline()` takes, however, is

1. an `stream&` (where the input comes from)
2. an `std::string&` (where the input ends up)
3. *optionally* a `char` (a delimiter, the default is `'\n'`)

Something like this should do:

```
std::string line;
while( std::getline(inFile, line) ) {
  // process line 
}
```

---

Note that your code is quite a mess. Let's walk through it:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

Since you are not using `argc` and `argv`, why pass them? Your compiler should warn you that they aren't used – which is just noise that might distract you from a compiler diagnostic that points at a real issue. Do this instead:

```
int main()
```

and the warning is gone.

```
string filename;
ifstream inFile;
```

Why define these at the top of the function, when they are used only further down? In C++, it is considered good style to define objects as late as possible, preferably when they can be initialized.

```
using namespace std;
```

This is a bad idea that [might hurt you badly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/140719). Just don't do it.

```
cin >> ( std::cin, filename );
```

I have no idea what this is supposed to do, let alone what it actually *does*, assuming it compiles. What you want instead, is this: `std::cin >> filename`. Note, however, that this prevents file names containing whitespace. Should that be a problem, employ `std::getline()` instead.

```
inFile.open( filename.c_str() );
```

This is where `inFile` should have been defined:

```
std::ifstream inFile( filename.c_str() );
```

Finally, your explicit closing of the file

```
inFile.close();
```

is unnecessary. The destructor of `std::ifstream` takes care of that anyway.

Comment: I still get the error when I do this:

    while( getline(fin, line))
{}

Comment: @user26093 I think the code you're showing us **isn't** the code that you actually have....Show us the code you actually have please.

Comment: @user26093 `getline(fin, line))`? What's `fin`?

Comment: yes. It gave me the same error. fin is supposed to be fileIn.

Comment: I'm just trying to read in every line of a file, do work on it, then read in the next line..

Comment: I see you have put `while( getline(getline(fin, line) )` into your question, complaining that it doesn't work either. I wonder what you think this nesting of `getline()` does? And the parentheses do not even match, so there's no way it could compile...

Comment: @user26093: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6892829/140719), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11881316/140719), and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1418587/140719). If that doesn't help, simply browse through [all my answers containing `std::getline()`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A140719+getline). I have given dozens of answers for it.